# How can I revise the sentence: "the hunter was waiting so that the leopard goes..."? It sounds a bit awkward

Tags: sentence-construction

I find this sentence a little awkward especially because of the verb “goes”. How can I revise it?

> *The hunter was waiting so that the leopard goes to the proper position for being shot.*

Comment: Do you mean "The hunter was waiting for the leopard to go to the proper position to be shot."? Additionally, if you have a second question about vocabulary, you will need to edit this question to remove it and create a new question.

Answer (score 3):

The hunter was waiting so that the leopard goes to the proper position for being shot, is a very unusual way of saying this.

It is like "The hungry man was waiting for the hamburger to be on his plate to get eaten".

I would advise you to revise it to something like this: 'The hunter was waiting for the leopard to get within shooting range.'

Answer (score 0):

I assume what you want to say is "The hunter was waiting for the leopard to go to a proper position to shoot".

Answer (score 0):

Typical collocations with wait are to *wait for* or *wait until* in the sense:

> to stay somewhere or not do something until something else happens, someone arrives etc. ([LDOCE](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/wait_1))

You can either wait for something to happen/someone to do something, or wait until something happens.

So your sentence could read, as JMB suggested:

> The hunter was waiting for the leopard to go to a proper position to be shot.

or since we are revising:

> The hunter was waiting for the leopard to get into a proper position to be shot.

Alternatively, you can use the construction with until (but I would change the tense, which would slightly alter the meaning, so I prefer the first construction):

> The hunter waited until the leopard was in a proper position to be shot.
>
> The hunter waited until the leopard went to a proper position to be shot.